# Why do we need an (adaptive) equalizer when we have a matched filter at the receiver?

Tags: digital-communications, receiver, decoder, digital-filter, digital-modulation

When both can perform the same task of reducing the effects of ISI, why use both and not just one at the receiver end?

Comment: Think about the resulting signal level.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Resulting in the sense? SNR at the output of matched filter? While a matched filter maximizes SNR for the desired signal, we can take a decision based on that, right? Whereas an equalizer attempts to produce an inverse channel transfer function to mitigate the effects of ISI. Both seem to work independently...